# How To Generate A List Of Possible Combination From A Set Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm a beginner coder, I have the code below

```py
def PossibleNum(List):
    DefaultSymbol = '%'
    NumDict = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
    FinishList = []
    for Item in List:
        for i in range(len(NumDict)):
            _item = Item.replace(DefaultSymbol,NumDict[i])
            FinishList.append(_item)
    return FinishList


List = ["AAAA%%","BBB%%%","CC%%C%"]
print (PossibleNum(List))
```

I'm trying to get every possible combination from NumDict by Replacing each of "%" into every possible NumDict

Wanted Output : `[AAAA00,AAAA01,AAAA02,AAAA03....,AAAA99]`

Current Output : `[AAAA11,AAAA22,AAAA33,AAAA,44,AAAA55,AAAA66]`

Comment: >> `AAAA,44` << - do you mean `AAAA44`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option using `itertools.product` to get all the possible inserts:

```py
import itertools     

l = ["AAAA%%","BBB%%%","CC%%C%"]    
DefaultSymbol = '%'
NumDict = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
out = []

for s in l:
    n = s.count(DefaultSymbol)
    prod = itertools.product(NumDict, repeat=n)
    for p in prod:
        tmp = s
        for i in p:
            tmp = tmp.replace(DefaultSymbol, i, 1)
        out.append(tmp)
```

Pretty straight forward; for each input list element get the number of replacements (count of '%'), calculate all possible elements to insert using `itertools.product`, then iterate over all these elements (`for p in prod`) and do the replacements, one at a time (`for i in p`, with replace count set to 1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.replace` with `count` parameter set to 1. To obtain the combinations, I used `str.format` method.

For example:

```
lst = ["AAAA%%","BBB%%%","CC%%C%"]
output = []

for i in lst:
    n = i.count('%')
    backup = i
    for v in range(10**n):
        i = backup
        for ch in '{:0{n}}'.format(v, n=n):
            i = i.replace('%', ch, 1)
        output.append(i)

# pretty print:
from pprint import pprint
pprint(output)
```

Prints:

```
['AAAA00',
 'AAAA01',
 'AAAA02',
 'AAAA03',

...all the way to:

 'CC99C5',
 'CC99C6',
 'CC99C7',
 'CC99C8',
 'CC99C9']
```